# Relationship between a linear-transformation and invariant subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ a vector over $F$  and $T: V\rightarrow V$ a linear transformation.

Prove that if $T$ is triangulizable, than it has a non-trivial invariant subspace.

Is this simply a case of taking a basis $B = \{v_1,...,v_n\}$ such that $[T]_B$ is triangular, than $Span(v_1)$ is an invariant sub-space for $T$?

If so - what is the logic behind this? Why is the triangular part plays a significant role here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is just fine. The triangulizable condition is just a simple sufficient condition for the existence of a nontrivial invariant subspace.

Of course, as you seem to be noticing, one might now wish to ponder some followup questions. For example, is triangulatizability a *necessary* condition for existence of a nontrivial invariant subspace? If not, are there more interesting sufficient conditions? Is there an interesting necessary and sufficient condition? Pondering these questions indeed leads to some *very* significant and important mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

As Lee Mosher already noted your reasoning is perfectly fine.

To see what significance the triangular part plays, recall that the $i$-th column of a matrix $[T]_B$ in a given ordered basis $B = (v_1, \dots, v_n)$ corresponds to the the image of the $i$-th basis vector under the linear transformation $T$.

If your matrix is for example upper-triangular, this yields that $v_1$ gets mapped to a scalar multiple of itself. Similarly $v_2$ gets mapped to a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$ and so on until $v_n$, which is a linear combination of all basis vectors.

In fact the existence of an ascending chain of invariant subspaces with dimensions $i = 1, \dots, n$ is a necessary and sufficient condition for a matrix to be triangulizable (see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1508475/triangular-matrices-t-invariant-subspaces)).